# How to get this prompt to work in my SQL PROC in SAS ? [Code Inside]

Tags: sql, sas, prompt

I did this below. What I'd like is to create a table where the prompt (TEXT) gets for values a where statement. Values are WHERE PERFORMING_FLAG = "Yes" , it display "Yes" to the user, and WHERE PERFORMING_FLAG = "No" that displays "No" to the user, and /* */ which displays "All"

So I wrote the code below, and it doesn't work.

What I want is being able To make the user choose between two options that are WHERE statement and one option that is nothing (so no WHERE statement).

How should I do my prompt or correct the code ? The prompt is &PERFORMING_FLAG

Or I guess there is a possibility to make it more clear, could be you please enlighten me ?

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE TRAVAIL.Q113_INPUTS AS

SELECT t1.ID_INTERNATIONAL,

      t1.NOM_TIERS,

      t1.CD_COTATION,

      t1.'Lb Secteur EIS GB'n,

      t1.'Zone Resp'n,

      t1.ID_FAC,

      t1.LB_ENGAGEMENT_GB,

      t1.'Type Encours'n,

      t1.'Type Encours GB'n,

      t1.IND_BILAN_HORS_BILAN,

      t1.DT_AUTO,

      t1.DT_ECH,

      t1.'Devise Final1'n,

      t1.'Devise Final'n,

      t1.SumOfMT_UTIL_EUR,

      t1.SumOfMT_AUTO_EUR,

      t1.PNU_conf,

      t1.'Regulatory_RWA'n,

      t1.SumOfMT_EXPO_IRBA,

      t1.TX_CCF_IRBA,

      t1.SumOfX_EDF1_IRBA,

      t1.SumOfX_GRR_IRBA,

      t1.SumOfX_MAT_IRBA,

      t1.PERFORMING_FLAG,

      t1.IND_CONF,

      t1.'Business Country'n,

      t1.'LB Pays Resp'n,

      t1.'Lib Metier 25'n,

      t1.'Lib act agg 25'n,

      t1.LB_GRP_AFFAIRE,

      t1.RATING_GROUPE,

      t1.C3_CLIENT_LINE,

      t1.CD_GRP_AFFAIRE,

      t1.Credit_Type_Profiling,

      t1.CD_TP_CTRP_CAPRI,

      t1.LIB_METIER_BFI,

      t1.FORTIS_FLAG,

      t1.CD_ENGAGEMENT,

      t1.LB_ENGAGEMENT

  FROM TRAVAIL.Q113_INPUTS_1 t1

   &PERFORMING_FLAG.;

QUIT;
```

Comment: Is this an EG prompt?

Comment: yeah, in what environment will this code be executed? Stored Process, Enterprise Guide?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [%WINDOW](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0ojc9rtfrzvbdn16kqd2c5mzobq.htm) statement? Or the [window statement from Data step](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n15a4llng8vzm0n14bv88cpejcuh.htm)?